# eloquent-Laravel-How to join 3 table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-design, eloquent

How can I get some data from 3 table using eloquent in laravel 5? I have 3 table, Team, Boards, User

Team Model:

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->withPivot('status','user_role')
                ->withTimestamps();
}


public function boards()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Boards::class)->withTimestamps();;
}
```

Boards Model

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->withPivot('status','user_role')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Table structure :

Team

```
id
team_name
```

Team_User (Pivot table)

```
id
user_id
team_id
```

Boards

```
id
board_name
```

Boards_user (pivot Table)

```
id
boards_id
user_id
```

The boards are belongs to team, and i want to get the data of boards that belong to a team (ex : team A) that assign to a user (ex: user1) but also member of team A.
How can i accomplish that?

Comment: You say that a `Board` belongs to a `Team`. So, every `User` related to the `Board` (`board_user` table) belongs to that `Team` right?

Comment: @HCK yeah that's correct, but not all team member are assign to that board. So i want boards that only assign to a user that also member of that team

Comment: Also, a Board belongs to a single Team or can belong to multiple teams?

Comment: @HCK 1 board only belongs to 1 team, but 1 team can have multiple boards

Answer (score 1):

According to your lastest comments:

- You don't need to relate `User` and `Board` directly. This can be accessed from the [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship from `User m----m Team`.
- A Board belongs to a single Team, a Team can have many boards. This is a [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship: `Team m-----1 Board`

So your tables should be structured this way:

```
users
=====
    - id    
    - ...

teams
=====
    - id
    - team_name

team_user
=========
    - id
    - team_id
    - user_id
    - status
    - user_role

boards
======
    - id
    - team_id
    - board_name
```

Then your relationships:

**User.php**

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this
       ->belongToMany(Team::class)
       ->withPivot('status','user_role');
}
```

**Team.php**

```
public function members()
{
    return $this
       ->belongToMany(User::class)
       ->withPivot('status','user_role');
}

public function boards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Board::class);
}
```

**Board.php**

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

So now you can access the boards related to a User specific team doing this:

```
$user_boards = User
                 ::find(1) // getting a User
                 ->teams() // accessing the Teams relationship
                 ->where('team_name', '=', 'My Team Name') // Constraining
                 ->first() // accessing the Team record
                 ->boards // getting the boards.
```

---

Additionally to that, you could add a shortcut in the User model to access the boards:

**User.php**

```
...

public function boardsOfTeam($teamName)
{
    return $this
       ->teams()
       ->where('team_name', '=', $teamName)
       ->first()
       ->boards;
}
```

Then in your controller (or wherever you want):

```
$user_boards = User::find(1)->boardsOfTeam('My Team Name');
```

This is totally optional, of course.